# Unable to output files in the directory on console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first file named `index5.js`

```
var server = require("./nonblockingserver");
var router = require("./nonblockingrouter");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers4");
var handle = {}
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
server.start(router.route, handle);
```

This is my second file named `nonblockingserver.js`

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function start(route, handle) {
function onRequest(request, response) {
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
route(handle, pathname, response);
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;
```

This is my third file named `nonblockingrouter.js`

```
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
handle[pathname](response);
} else {
console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("404 Not found");
response.end();
}
}
exports.route = route;
```

This is my third file named `requestHandlers4.js`

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
function start(response) {
console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write(stdout);
response.end();
});
}
function upload(response) {
console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello Upload");
response.end();
}
exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

When I write `http://localhost:8888/start` in my browser it should display all the files in the directory but instead it is printing nothing on browser.

Comment: It works for me.  What does your console output say? Does the node process have permission to list the directory contents?

Comment: The console says `The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.`

Comment: @TimCooper How to check whether `the node process have permission to list the directory contents? `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this,

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
```

to,

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"});
```

Comment: console output is same?

Comment: Yes console output is same.