# Unable to install formidable in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This may sound like a duplicate question, but, believe me, it's not. I couldn't find any source detailing the same error and how to remedy it:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\nodejsfiles>npm install formidable
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: formidable
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\npm-registry-
client\get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\npm-regis
try-client\request.js:32:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\
utils\npm-registry-client\request.js:137:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_
modules\request\main.js:109:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\request\main.js:198:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\request\main.js:356:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1258:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "formidable"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\nodejsfiles
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-3
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: formidable
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\Desktop\nodejsfiles\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: The documentation advises to run `npm install formidable@latest`. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @FredericHamidi No it doesn't make a difference.BTW I am reading this [book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) and I have installed node.js version 0.6.10.

Comment: Why won't you install the latest version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this works

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Quoted from ["message failed to fetch from registry" while trying to install any module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913141/installing-from-npm-fails)

Anyway I recommend updating to latest versions of `nodejs` and `npm`.

Comment: Thanks it worked Could you also please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427871/unable-to-output-files-in-the-directory-on-console)